# How to assign values to words in list based on predetermined values letters (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, list, loops

There is a list with words (wordListReal).
Every letter in the alphabet has an assigned value (see code).

Now the question is how to obtain the value of all the letter values added together *per word*, then divided by the number of letters in that word.

I tried this, but strangely enough it returns only lots of 0, 1 and 2, which is incorrect:

```
# wordListReal = ["mystery", "strange", "why", "how", "thinking", "solution", "gratitude", "life"]

frequencyPointList = []
points1 = 0
points2 = 0
for word1 in wordListReal: 
    points1 = 0                                                                                    
    for letter1 in word1:
        if letter1 in {"e" , "a" , "r" , "i" , "o"}:
            points1 += 1
        elif letter1 in {"t" , "n" , "s" , "l" , "c"}:
            points1 += 2
        elif letter1 in {"u" , "d" , "p" , "m" , "h"}:
            points1 += 3
        elif letter1 in {"g" , "b" , "f" , "y" , "w"}:
            points1 += 4
        elif letter1 in {"k" , "v" , "x" , "z" , "j" , "q"}:
            points1 += 5
    numberLetters1 = len(word1)
    points2 = points1 // numberLetters1
    frequencyPointList.append(points2)

print(frequencyPointList)
```

Eventually the results need to be in a list, not in a dictionary.

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: through in between printing it becomes more clear where the problem lies, but not how to solve it yet. Points1 and numberLetters1 are calculated correctly and they are both integers, but when dividing them through each other to arrive at points2 something goes wrong!

```
wordListReal = ["mystery", "strange", "why", "how", "thinking", "solution", "gratitude", "life"]

frequencyPointList = []
points1 = 0
points2 = 0
for word1 in wordListReal: 
    points1 = 0                                                                                    
    for letter1 in word1:
        if letter1 in {"e" , "a" , "r" , "i" , "o"}:
            points1 += 1
        elif letter1 in {"t" , "n" , "s" , "l" , "c"}:
            points1 += 2
        elif letter1 in {"u" , "d" , "p" , "m" , "h"}:
            points1 += 3
        elif letter1 in {"g" , "b" , "f" , "y" , "w"}:
            points1 += 4
        elif letter1 in {"k" , "v" , "x" , "z" , "j" , "q"}:
            points1 += 5
    print("points1: " + str(points1))
    print(type(points1))
    numberLetters1 = len(word1)
    print("numberLetters1: " + str(numberLetters1))
    print(type(numberLetters1))
    points2 = (int(points1) // int(numberLetters1))
    print("points2: " + str(points2))
    print(type(points2))
    frequencyPointList.append(points2)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The values of the letters per word added together, divided by the number of letters in the word

Comment: post short example of wordlist and its excepted output.

Comment: `//` versus `/`. `//` is used for the floor of the division (eg. it will round down to the lowest `int`). Use `/` instead. See [this article](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-floor-division/) for details

Comment: Thank you and many apologies, it turns out the output was right after all.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep track of your variables:

1. `points1` should always be `0` at the begining of your loop
2. You accumulate the points in the variable inside the `letter1` loop
3. After the loop in the previous step, you calculate the average points per word (i.e. redefine `points1`)
4. Add the previous value to your list
5. Keep going

This means:

```
for word1 in wordListReal: 
    points1 = 0
    for letter1 in word1:
        # if ...
            # points1 += ...
    toDivideBy = len(word1)
    points1 = (int(points1) // int(toDivideBy))
    frequencyPointList.append(points1)
```

At the moment, your code does not reflect this logic, instead it is forcing the first value to always be the same and misses the value of the last word.

Some tips to improve your code further:

- Use `if`/`elif` (and `else` if necessary) to avoid calculating conditions multiple times when you don't need. For example, you have multiple `if` statements and all of them will be calculated on each iteration. Using `if`/`elif` the calculation will stop the first time that condition is `True`.
- Use `print` to check how your code is progressing, for example: print the current word and in the inner loop print the letter and current `points1` total to confirm that the total matches your expectations. You could also print the value of `frequencyPointList` at the end of each iteration in your outer loop.

Comment: Thank you, this made it possible to improve the code. But the core problem still persists... I will edit the question

Comment: Thank you again, the output was right after all!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that seem odd to me:

1. the logic for checking each letter seems incorrect, it can be done a lot easier.
2. use `elif` instead of `if` as this will speed up the process. A letter can only match one time.
3. This calls for a method...

EDIT: changed the logic a bit and used the provided word list as an example

```py
def get_points_for_word(word: str) -> tuple:
    total_points = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in "eario":
            total_points += 1
        elif letter in "tnslc":
            total_points += 2
        elif letter in "udpmh":
            total_points += 3
        elif letter in "gbfyw":
            total_points += 4
        elif letter in "xvxzjq":
            total_points += 5
    return (total_points, total_points / len(word))


wordListReal = [
    "mystery",
    "strange",
    "why",
    "how",
    "thinking",
    "solution",
    "gratitude",
    "life",
]

print("Word                 | TOT | AVE ")
print("---------------------+-----+-----")
for word in wordListReal:
    total_points, average_points = get_points_for_word(word)
    print(f"{word:20} | {total_points:3} | {average_points:.3}")
```

This gives the output below:

```
Word                 | TOT | AVE 
---------------------+-----+-----
mystery              |  17 | 2.43
strange              |  13 | 1.86
why                  |  11 | 3.67
how                  |   8 | 2.67
thinking             |  15 | 1.88
solution             |  14 | 1.75
gratitude            |  18 | 2.0
life                 |   8 | 2.0
```

Comment: It for sure is a clean approach, but the outcome contains the same problem as the original code. Your example has the outcome "1", which does not corresponds with the sum of the values of the letters, divided by the number of letters in the word

Comment: that is not the output that it gives me. It gives me `1.8571428571428572`

Comment: check the updated answer, I've used your wordlist as input. Your issue might be in a different location, as it's not possible for my code to return a 1 unless the word is only using letters that are worth one point. I think you might be casting as an `int` somewhere

Comment: aaaand I found your issue: you are using `//` instead of `/`. This gives the floor of the division, instead of the complete division. See [this article](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-floor-division/)

Comment: Thank you again, the output was right after all!